# Visual Studio doesn't want me to code or something (Deleting debug)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

So I was checking the files for my C++ game, and I see the .exe file already created. I coded a bit to see if it works, and when I debugged it, it said the .exe file was not found. And indeed it was not there. Did I do something wrong? Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFMl\Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(320, 480), "The Game!");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event e;
        while (window.pollEvent(e))
        {
            if (e.type == Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(Color::White);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't have compiling or linking errors, you should check the project settings in your IDE

Comment: The question's title is not useful. It should give readers a quick way to know approximately what the question is about.

Comment: If the exe is not where the linker output log says it was written, then check your antivirus in case it was quarantined.

Comment: It will delete the .exe before it creates a new one. If it didn't create a new one then your code probably has errors.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your snippet and it worked fine.

Try to turn off your antivirus software, or test it on other devices.
[image]